# How to install tortoisegit

Tags: windows, git, tortoise-svn, tortoise-git

How to install tortoisegit without admin rights ?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is not possible because Setup tries to register the Shell extension DLLs into the system part of the registry.

Comment: But why should this part be necessary ? What feature does this provide ? Maybe I don't need it... couldn't I at least recompile the project without this feature ?

Comment: Or maybe I could just not use the setup, and use only the executables, in a portable fashion ? Where can I get the executables ? Like if I only want tortoisediff, for example.

Comment: the purpose of all Tortoise tools is to add them as shellextension to the Explorer. You should look for alternative tools which run as portable version.

Comment: I just want a graphical user interface for diff comparisons, what would you recommend ?

Comment: Try Portable SmartGit: http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Programming/Portable-SmartGit.shtml

Comment: It is not open source, nor free for commercial use. Is there an alterrnative ?

Comment: buy a license if you use it in commercial usage.